# Web API controller parameterized constructor called only once, parameterless constructor on subsequent requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm attempting to use Unity to inject a dependency per this article:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver

Here is what I have in my global.asax

```
void ConfigureApi(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var unity = new UnityContainer();
        unity.RegisterType<CustomerController>();
        unity.RegisterType<TPS.Data.Can.IUnitOfWork, TPS.Data.Can.EFRepository.UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        config.DependencyResolver = new IoCContainer(unity);
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        ConfigureApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }
```

Here is my API controller:

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    private TPS.Data.Can.IRepository<tblCustomer> _repo;
    private TPS.Data.Can.IUnitOfWork _uow;
    public CustomerController() { }

    public CustomerController(TPS.Data.Can.IUnitOfWork uow) {
        _uow = uow;
        _repo = uow.CustomerRepository;
    }

    // GET api/customer/5
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Get()
    {
        string identity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        //REFACTOR THIS
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(identity))
            identity = "chardie";

        var customers = from c in _repo.Get()
                       where c.SalesRep == identity
                       select new Customer
                       {
                           IDCUST = null,
                           CustCode = c.CustCode,
                           CustName = c.CustName
                       };

        return customers.ToList();
    }
```

This works when I first start debugging my application. If I set a breakpoint in the parameterized constructor, the breakpoint will be hit when I hit the Web API for the first time. When I hit refresh in my browser, the constructor does *not* get called, the dependency doesn't get injected, and the Get() action throws an exception because the expected repository is null.

Can anyone tell me why my constructor isn't being called after the first request?

Thanks!

Chris

**EDIT**

FWIW, I removed the parameterless constructor entirely from the Web API controller, and on my second request to it, I get the exception:

```
Type 'TPS.Website.Api.CustomerController' does not have a default constructor
```

So it appears I'm getting my repo dependency injected on the first request, but after that every instantiation of the Web API controller is done through the parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying a lifecycle for the controller. [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff648211.aspx)

> If you do not specify a value for the lifetime, the instance will have
>   the default container-controlled lifetime. It will return a reference
>   to the original object on each call to Resolve.

If the `IUnitOfWork` dependency is transient, then the controller should be transient too. So try

```
unity.RegisterType<CustomerController>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

This might not solve the whole problem but it sounds like part of it. You certainly shouldn't need the parameterless constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I still get the same behaviour, even after changing the lifetime. And I checked the article I'm lifting from, and he is using HierarchicalLifetimeManager.

Answer (score 0):

I had this as I was returning my resolver for my dependency scope using this and then disposing the container in the dispose.  So after the first request the container was disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's because you're not using singleton pattern for the Unity Container.

Have a private static variable instead of the var container = new UnityContainer();

```
internal static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() => new UnityContainer());
```

Then access within code using the .Value property.